# Calculate the probability that a certain percent of the products supplied by a factory are sold

Tags: bayes-theorem

**The problem:**

A shop sells 2600 pieces of a certain product, supplied by factories A, B, and C, in the following quantities: 3000 pieces from factory A, 2600 pieces from factory B, and 4200 pieces from factory C. Knowing that the factories supply products with the same quality, find the probability that exactly 820 pieces sold come from factory A, 500 from factory B, and 1280 from factory C.

**Solving attempt:**

Let S be the event that a piece is sold, and A,B,C, the events that the piece comes from the factory A, B and C, respectively.

The total quantity in the 'warehouse' is 3000+2600+4200=9800 pieces.

So **P(S) = 2600/9800 = 26/98.**

Also, **P(A)= 26/98, P(B) =30/98, and P(C)=42/98.**

As all the three factories supply products with the same quality, every single piece has the same chance of being sold, so
**P(S|A)=P(S|B)=P(S|C) = 1/3.**

Using Bayes' formula: **P(A|B)= (P(A) * P(B|A))/P(B)**, I tried to calculate the probability for each factory, adapting the formula as : **P(A|S)=(P(A)*P(S|A))/P(S)**, getting the following results:

**P(A|S)= 10/26, P(B|S)=12/26 and P(C|S)=14/26.**

Which is obviously wrong, as their sum is 36/26, clearly higher than 1.

Comment: There are $\binom{9800}{2600}$ equally likely ways to choose $2600$ pieces from the $9800$. How many ways are there to choose $820$ from A, $500$ from B, and $1280$ from C?

Comment: $\binom{3000}{820}$ * $\binom{2600}{500}$ * $\binom{4200}{1280}$

Comment: Yes. Now you can write down an *expression* for the probability. If we want to evaluate numerically, there is more work to do. Appropriate software will handle it. If it has to be approximated "by hand" I would use the Stirling approximation to the factorials.

Comment: The answer seems to be $\frac{($\binom{3000}{820}$*$\binom{6200}{500}$*$\binom{4200}{1280}$)}/{$\binom{9800}{2600}$}$, which is approximatively. $1.04 * (10)^(-248)$. Can't this problem be solved using Bayes' Theorem, though?

Comment: Sorry for bad mathjax, I meant $\frac{\binom{3000}{820}*\binom{4200}{1280}*\binom{2600}{500}}{\binom{9800}{2600}}$

Comment: The problem is not very clearly worded. I assumed they had $3000$ in the warehouse from Factory A, and so on, and sold $2600$ randomly chosen items. I do not see any conditional probabilities in the problem.

Comment: I understand. The course revised basic probabilities and introduced Bayes' theorem, and looking just like the other Bayes exercises, I thought it should be solved using the theorem. Thank you for taking your time to help me!

Comment: You are welcome. As you mention, there are standard problems in which Factory A produces $5\%$ defectives, Factory B produces $7\%$ defectives,  and so on, and we are asked for the probability an item came from Factory A given that it is defective. That's a conditional probability (or Bayes' Theorem) problem. This one is not.